# how do I call function when the user presses enter on the input

Tags: javascript, html, input, keypress

I want call function when the user presses enter on the input.

```
<input type='text' id='name'></input>
```

I found this code but it doesn't work.

```
$("#name").bind('keypress', function(e) {
if(e.which == 13) {
    alert('You pressed enter!');
}
});
```

Comment: If your input is in a form make sure to prevent the default submit event, that may be the issue.

Comment: It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/6CLw3/

Comment: try `e.keyCode == 13` instead.  I don't believe `which` is supported cross-browser.

Comment: The input element doesn't require a closing element. If you are using xhtml then use <input type='text' id='name' />

Comment: @broofa - actually, `event.which` is normalized in jQuery, and works everywhere.

Comment: And, the posted code should work, even if it's not great, but make sure jQuery is loaded and the DOM is ready

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you include the JQuery library? Your code appears to work fine in Chrome.

You could also do:

```
$("#name").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dMt55/

Non Jquery version:

```
document.getElementById('name').onkeypress = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the same code without JQuery? Just pure Js.

Comment: Edited to add non-jquery version.

Comment: How can I do this NonJquery version so it onkeydown of arrow keys and of document.body?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this;

```
<input type='text' id='name' />

$("#name").bind('keypress', function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode== 13) { //Enter
                  // your code 
                }
});
```

Comment: just use `var code = event.keyCode`.  No need to test if it's defined or not.  (The `which` property has been deprecated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

Answer (score 1):

You can wire up your own custom event
.Try this

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='name'></input>
```

Jquery

```
$('#name').bind("enterKey",function(e){
   //do stuff here
});
$('#name').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x7HVQ/